# How derivatives of SeqView (like SeqViewRMS) appear?

Tags: scala

In "Programming in Scala" (Section 24.15, Views), I saw next code:

```
scala> val v = Vector(1 to 10: _*)
v: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

v.view map (_ + 1)
res69: scala.collection.SeqView[Int,Seq[_]] = SeqViewM(...)
```

It's said

> ... is in essence a wrapper that records the fact that a map with
>   function (_ + 1) needs to be applied on the vector v.

But I can't figure out where those SeqViewR*M*S* are. Are there any already created classes, like Function1..22 (what I didn't find, and it's a bit impossible to create all combinations), or these are created dynamically?

Comment: It seems they're generated 'dynamically' more or less. Mapping three times over a view gives you `SeqViewMMM`, while doing `v.view.map(...).map(...).map(...).drop(3).take(4)` results in `SeqViewMMMSS`. I have no idea how it's really implemented, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SeqViewR`, `SeqViewRMS`, etc. are not in fact classes, but only text descriptions for views. The same class will use a different description depending on how much transformation it represents, e.g. `SeqViewR` and `SeqViewRR` are usually the same class.

The relevant code is the `viewToString` method in `TraversableViewLike`:

```
protected[this] def viewIdString: String = ""
protected[this] def viewIdentifier: String = ""
def viewToString = stringPrefix + viewIdString + "(...)"
```

`stringPrefix` is the original type of the view, e.g. `SeqView`. `viewIdString` is the `R`/`RMS`/ whatever part. When you invoke a method like `map` or `take` or `reverse`, you obtain a class that implements `TraversableViewLike.Transformed`, which has the following definition:

```
final override protected[this] def viewIdString = self.viewIdString + viewIdentifier
```

and then in each implementation something like:

```
final override protected[this] def viewIdentifier = "R"
```

This `viewIdString` method takes the `viewIdString` of the original view and attaches the appropriate letter. This works recursively, so the result of `view.reverse.reverse.reverse` is a class with a viewIdString of `"RRR"`. Note that no classes are being dynamically generated, only their descriptions.